# Automating import of multiple rasters as layers into tilemill?

Tags: tilemill, mbtiles

How do I automate the import of raster tiffs into tile mill?

I have well over 100 files.

I have many warped tiff files ready to be imported as individual layers into tile mill so they can be saved out as a single mbtiles file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the GDAL utility, [`gdalbuildvrt`](http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html), to create a mosaicked VRT as a raster input to TileMill. [It seems to be a recommended approach](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/discrete-raster-data/#build_a_virtual_dataset).

Comment: ..hmm, I may have misunderstood your use case. apologies. but this might still be useful for someone who stumbles through with other intentions, so I'll leave the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need 100 of layers, use `gdal_merge 1.tif 2.tif ... 100.tif -o single.tif` to merge them into one.

Alternatively, you may use the fact `project.mml` is a plain-text JSON file. Open in in a text editor (notepad will do), find a block corresponding to one of your raster layers, and copy it required number of times, changing tiff file name.